# How to Render Mapbox Map in React.js Without Exposing API Key using Mapbox GL JS and Laravel Backend?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, laravel-sanctum

I'm working on a React.js project where I need to render a Mapbox map. I've created a custom map style in Mapbox Studio and want to use it in my application. To avoid exposing my Mapbox API key on the client side, I set up a Laravel backend using Laravel Sanctum to handle the Mapbox API requests.

Here's what I've done so far:

In Laravel, I created a MapboxController.php that retrieves the style using the Mapbox Styles API and my secret key.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class MapboxController extends Controller
{
    public function getMapStyle()
    {

        $response = Http::get('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{username}/{style_id}?access_token='.env('MAPBOX_API_KEY'));


        return response()->json($response->json());
    }
}
```

The Laravel API returns the response to my React app, that should initialize the map like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import "./Map.css";

const Map = () => {
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("MY_BACKEND_URL")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data); //Logging the response for debugging, the data arrives as expected

        // Initializing the map with the data
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: mapContainer.current,
          style: data.style,
          center: [9.984395, 51.145088],
          zoom: 8,
          attributionControl: false,
          logoPosition: "bottom-left",
        });

        const attribution = new mapboxgl.AttributionControl({});
        map.dragRotate.disable();
        map.touchZoomRotate.disableRotation();
        map.addControl(attribution, "bottom-right");

        return () => map.remove();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Fehler beim Laden der Karte: ", error);
      });
  }, []);

  return <div ref={mapContainer} style={{ height: "100vh" }} />;
};

export default Map;
```

However, I'm encountering an issue where Mapbox still requires an API key on the client side. Here's the error message I receive in the console:

```
Map.js:32 Fehler beim Laden der Karte:  Error: An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL. See https://docs.mapbox.com/api/overview/#access-tokens-and-token-scopes
    at e.cS._makeAPIURL (mapbox.js:221:23)
    at e.cS.normalizeStyleURL (mapbox.js:80:21)
    at kr.loadURL (style.js:390:40)
    at Map._updateStyle (map.js:2019:28)
    at Map.setStyle (map.js:1994:25)
    at new Map (map.js:658:18)
    at Map.js:15:21
```

I'm looking for a way to render my map in React without having the API key in the frontend. Is there a way to securely use Mapbox in this scenario, where the API key remains hidden and only the necessary data is sent to the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to render my map in React without having the API key in the frontend

You can't, but that's ok. What you do instead if [add URL restrictions to your API key](https://docs.mapbox.com/accounts/guides/tokens/#url-restrictions)

Comment: I see... that's something Mapbox should add in my opinion... Thank you!
So the best practice here would just be to use restrictions and maybe the Mapbox Tokens API to rotate the tokens?

Comment: URL restrictions will get you a very very long ways (maybe even as far as you'll ever need to go). If you have the time/effort (and risk warrants it), serving your API token from your backend to your FE and using your BE to rotate client side API keys is a great second layer.